# Accessing elements of [[[i j k l]]]

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, hough-transform

I've recently started working with Python and image processing. The HoughLinesP function from CV outputted this "[[[465 391 521 391]]]" and I need to export the values to an excel sheet afterwards. So, I need to access each of those elements individually.

How would I go about accessing those elements and storing them for later use?

Thank-you for your help!

Comment: Are you using openCV?

Comment: That is the not valid python. Is it supposed to be `[[['456 391 521 391']]]`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using openCV. I meant by putting it in quotes that that was the output, not that the output was a quote: I'm sorry for the confusion there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlinesp#cv2.HoughLinesP) is the corresponding documentation. The result of calling the function is an array, with the points you need. Here is how you could access them and store them to a CSV:

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(...)
with open('tmp.csv', 'w') as f:
    for l in lines:
        f.write(','.join(str(x) for x in l) + "\n")
```

The file `tmp.csv` should contain data that can be opened in Excel.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly for what I was needing.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way, with `csv`:

```
import csv

# Assuming lines is already defined and in scope.

with open('tmp.csv', 'w') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
   writer.writerow(lines)
```